# Ruby file update notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I'm working on an Rails app which reads a CSV file on the server. However, the CSV file keeps getting updated.

My SQLite database is populated from the contents of this CSV file. Is there a way to run a Ruby script as soon as the file is modified and make changes in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into some parts of the [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) gem. Specifically the [lib/vendor](https://github.com/guard/guard/tree/master/lib/vendor) directory seem to contain the code you need for different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) gem.

It integrates with stuff like libnotify, fsevent stuff so as to avoid polling, although it does also support polling as a less efficient fallback.

Answer (score 0):

How is the CSV file updated? If it is updated by some program that you have control over, then you can add a code within the update routine to run the ruby script that upgrades the SQLite database as soon as the CSV file is updated.

Otherwise, you can do polling to check for a change in the CSV file.